# to zoom pages, what chrome command(s) should I use?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am using chrome on Mac. Yesterday everything is OK. In particular, both 2 shortcuts

> <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>
>
> <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

can zoom pages, like click the + button shown in the figure below.

[image]

Now, the one without <kbd>shift</kbd>, namely, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> , does not work.

I am trying to bind <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> in Mac System Preferences, what chrome command(s) should I use.

[image]

Comment: Browser zoom should just be Cmd & "the keys with  - & + on them" you shouldn't need the shift key to activate either. If you have a 10-key you can test there too.

Answer (score -1):

Let's check out the Accessibility section, it's there!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That zoom the OS screen. I want to just zoom the pages in chrome.